# Why the player is walking through objects in scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Instead walking on the ground he walk through it same for the ship and debris the other objects. He stay on the ground on the terrain but all the other objects in the scene he walk through it.

In the past i added Mesh Collider to the ship sapceship and checked the Convex turned the Convex on so it worked fine. but now i tried to add Mesh Collider almost to everything in the scene and it didn't change anything.

[image: Scene]

The scene is not my own but there is nothing speical i think. A terrain camera and objects. I added the ThirdPersonController.

Maybe there is a way to solve it making a new script in c# ? So far i could not find solution.

Comment: For now i solved it by selecting all objects and models in scene and added to all of them Mesh Collider. But is it a good idea to add to all of them a Mesh Collider ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the collider of the Player is big enought to hold the model. And also that the terrain collider is adjusted to the terrain.

Comment: So i need to have no mesh colliders at all ? On the ThirdPersoncontroller there is a Capsule Collider and on the Terrain there is a Terrain Collider. So this is all i need only this two ? So to delete all the mesh colliders i added to all objects and models ?

Comment: I didn't read the comment that you solved with Mesh Collider. All object who needs collisions, need colliders, about what colliders do you need, it depends, if u have a box or a rectangular object, just use box collider but if you have a complicated mesh its fine to use mesh collider. Read about what colliders unity have and what fits you best.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Center(Y) value of CapsulCollider